# Update displayed stats for migrated questions

Tags: feature-request, migrated-questions

I posted a well received Q&A on StackOverflow that was migrated to SuperUser: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090)

If I search on StackOverflow for `[batch-file] rename wildcards`, I find the following right at the top:

[image]

The cross-referencing of migrated questions is great, but the stats are misleading. If I am a batch file developer looking for information about how RENAME works with wildcards I would think there is no answer and I wouldn't bother clicking the link. I would miss out on valuable information.

If instead I saw the live stats that are available on SuperUser I would see that there is an accepted answer and the question is popular. I would definitely click on that link.

[image]

Can the sites be modified to show the live stats for cross-referenced migrated questions?